# Nicematrix with \Ddots leading to empty cell

Tags: nicematrix

I'm trying to draw a square matrix with `\Cdots`, `\Vdots` and `\Ddots`, all of which need to terminate in empty cells. Two problems arise: (i) the `ddots` is not close to 45 degrees (I think it's calculating the angle from the diagonal elements `a_{11}` and `a_{22}`) and (ii) the `cdots` and `vdots` overshoot the `ddots`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{pNiceMatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\Cdots\\ a_{21}&a_{22}&&\\\Vdots &&\Ddots\end{pNiceMatrix}\]

\end{document}
```

I've tried adding corners and phantom dots to populate the empty cells but the matrix is larger than necessary, and has an empty last column.

```
\[\begin{pNiceMatrix}[corners]a_{11}&a_{12}&\Cdots&\phantom{.}\\ a_{21}&a_{22}&&&\\\Vdots &&\Ddots&\\\phantom{.}&&&\phantom{.}\end{pNiceMatrix}\]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `nicematrix`, it's always a bit complicated with dotted lines with an open extremity...

Here is a suggestion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{pNiceMatrix}[xdots/shorten-start=5pt]
  a_{11}  & a_{12}  & \Cdots \\ 
  a_{21}  & a_{22}  & \\
  \Vdots &         & \NotEmpty
\CodeAfter \line{2-2}{3-3}
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]